# How to parsing Json in Zoho CRM

Tags: json, zoho

How to parsing json in Zoho

My Input Is Below

```
{"projects":[{"is_strict":"no","role":"admin","owner_name":"James Lozos","IS_BUG_ENABLED":true,"created_date_long":1502180785112,"owner_id":"647743525","link":{"task":{"url":"https://projectsapi.zoho.com/restapi/portal/sqmscrm/projects/1115954000000093005/tasks/"}}}]}
```

Output : We Need Above url : https://projectsapi.zoho.com/restapi/portal/sqmscrm/projects/1115954000000093005/tasks/

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what programming language, you are using.
For example: with Python, we can use json library like this

> import json
>
> txt = '{"projects":[{"is_strict":"no","role":"admin","owner_name":"James Lozos","IS_BUG_ENABLED":true,"created_date_long":1502180785112,"owner_id":"647743525","link":{"task":{"url":"https://projectsapi.zoho.com/restapi/portal/sqmscrm/projects/1115954000000093005/tasks/"}}}]}'
>
> obj = json.loads(txt)

or in context of result from api you can use .json() function of requests (Python again)

> import requests
>
> result = requests.get('url-of-api')
>
> obj = result.json()